# Coriander is growing long in hight

Tags: trees

I want to grow Indian coriander from indian seeds in Germany. 
First I tried it in cold temperatures (15° c) but it grows very tall (3 cm )with 2 leaves and then it died 
Second time I had grown it in hot atmosphere with UV lights in room, then also same it start grow with 2 leaves and increase hight till 4 cm and after 10 15 days it will died.

Can anyone give me reason for this.
And how can I grow perfect coriander in pot with UC rays?[image][image]

Comment: My experience is that tall (leggy) seedlings is caused by warm soil , but 15C does not sound warm for a warm weather plant like coriander or cilantro . But the seedlings should be that size in about 3 days so they appear not to be getting enough of the "right "light.

Comment: Too cold. I have given up growing it except in the hottest weather. I hope that is not Ultraviolet (UV) light, most other lights are good, but only up to 16 hours a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [etiolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiolation) where a plant that is receiving insufficient light attempts to grow taller in order to reach into direct sunlight.  In this case, it means you don't have enough light and need to either find a sunnier spot or add supplemental lighting.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is due to low light levels. You can see the seedlings are tending to bend over in one direction (presumably towards where the light source was). UV won't solve your problems - much of the light plants need is in the visible spectrum. A grow light that has actually been developed for plant growth should improve things. In this instance, the temperature you mention won't have much of an impact. Higher temperatures will increase the metabolic rate of a plant meaning that they will need to photosynthesis more rapidly to keep up with their energy requirements (and therefore need brighter light).

Another issue is that these are massively overcrowded. Coriander (*Coriandrum sativum*) can grow up to a 1m tall in my garden (UK). This is going to cause issues - firstly, it increases competition for light. Secondly, at some point, one of those seedlings is going to die and with the rest packed so tightly the others around it will die as well. That pot is only big enough for one plant, so put two or three seeds in to start and thin out to one at the first true leaf stage. You may see pots with lots of seedlings like this being sold in the supermarket - these are produced in ideal conditions and are not intended for long term growth. They are really just a way of selling a bunch of coriander that will stay fresh for longer.